# Java Error - Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException

Tags: java

I wonder if anyone can help me with my code?

I am doing an integration with Bitfinex and sending POST but I am getting     this error and others in the Log.

Not sure if the problem is in the 'main' class or on the header of the request. I did check the credentials and they are correct.

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't 
>   find Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL:  (https:
>   api.bitfinex.com/v1/balances/) -> {"message:"Could not find a  key
>   matching the given X-BFX-APIKEY."} bundle
>
> at java.util.logging.Logger.setupResourceInfo(Logger.java:1946) at
>   java.util.logging.Logger.(Logger.java:380) at
>   java.util.logging.LogManager.demandLogger(LogManager.java:554) at
>   java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:455) at
>   java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:553) at
>   br.com.bitfinex.ExecutorBitfin$HttpPost.executaPostBalance(ExecutorBitfin.java:112)
>   at
>   br.com.bitfinex.ExecutorBitfin.executeRequest(ExecutorBitfin.java:191)
>   at br.com.bitfinex.ExecutorBitfin.main(ExecutorBitfin.java:196)

```
public class ExecutorBitfin {
private static String APIKEY = "xxxx";
private static String APISECRET = "xxxx";
private static final String HOST = "https://api.bitfinex.com";
private static final String PATH = "/v1/balances/";
private static final String ALGORITHM_HMACSHA384 = "HmacSHA384";
private static final String TAG = 
ExecutorBitfin.class.getSimpleName();

private long nonce = System.currentTimeMillis();

public long getNonce() {
    return ++nonce;
}

public ExecutorBitfin(String APIKEY, String APISECRET) {
    this.APIKEY = APIKEY;
    this.APISECRET = APISECRET;
}



    public class HttpPost {

    private Map<String,String> headers;
    private String body;

    public HttpPost(Map<String,String> headers, String body){
        this.headers = headers;
        this.body = body;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    public String executaPostBalance() throws IOException {
        String sResponse;
        String method = "POST";
        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        try{
            URL url1 = new URL(HOST + PATH);
            con = (HttpsURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod(method);


            send post
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);

            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
            jo.put("request", PATH);
            jo.put("nonce", Long.toString(getNonce()));

            String payload = jo.toString();
            String payload_base64 = 
Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(payload.getBytes());
            String payload_sha384hmac = HmacDigest (payload_base64, 
APISECRET, ALGORITHM_HMACSHA384);

            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
"application/json");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            con.addRequestProperty("X-BFX-APIKEY", APIKEY);
            con.addRequestProperty("X-BFX-PAYLOAD", payload_base64);
            con.addRequestProperty("X-BFX-SIGNATURE",   
payload_sha384hmac);



            InputStream in = new 
BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
            return convertStreamToString(in);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new IOException(e.getClass().getName(), e);
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            throw new IOException(e.getClass().getName(), e);
            } catch (IOException e) {

            String errMsg = e.getLocalizedMessage();

            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    sResponse = 
convertStreamToString(con.getErrorStream());
                    errMsg += " -> " + sResponse;
                    Logger.getLogger(TAG, errMsg);
                    return sResponse;
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    errMsg += " Error on reading error-stream. -> " + 
e1.getLocalizedMessage();
                    Logger.getLogger(TAG, errMsg);
                    throw new IOException(e.getClass().getName(), e1);
                }
            } else {
                throw new IOException(e.getClass().getName(), e);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            String msg = "Error on setting up the connection to 
server";
            throw new IOException(msg, e);
        } finally {
            if (con != null) {
                con.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }

            private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) 
throws IOException {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line;
                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line).append('\n');
                    }
                } finally {
                    try {
                        is.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return sb.toString();
            }





    @SuppressWarnings("finally")
    private String HmacDigest(String msg, String keyString, String 
algo) {
        String digest = null;
        try {
            SecretKeySpec key = new 
SecretKeySpec((keyString).getBytes("UTF-8"), algo);
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algo);
            mac.init(key);

            byte[] bytes = mac.doFinal(msg.getBytes("ASCII"));

            StringBuffer hash = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & bytes[i]);
                if (hex.length() == 1) {
                    hash.append('0');
                }
                hash.append(hex);
            }
            digest = hash.toString();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return digest;
    }

    }


    public void executeRequest() throws IOException{
        Map<String,String> header = new HashMap<>();

        HttpPost executePost = new HttpPost(header, null);
        executePost.executaPostBalance();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new ExecutorBitfin(APIKEY, APISECRET).executeRequest();
    }
    }
```

Comment: The MissingResourceException is related to a missing resource bundle. Possibly because of your call to e.getLocalizedMessage(). This you can probably ignore. I can't tell for sure since you don't have the line numbers above. The real issue though is the HTTP 401 (unauthorized). Maybe check your credentials? Normally 401 is returned due to missing credentials in basic auth...

Comment: `"message:"Could not find a key matching the given X-BFX-APIKEY."` = bad API key